# Vertical line in report (rdlc)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report

I am creating an Invoice in report data (rdlc), I want to put vertical line between the columns like

Sl | Description  | Qty | Rate | Amount 
    |                        |        |          |

My report contains header and footer section also.
For vertical line I used line control, it perfectly works on the first page. But line is not visible on the second page. I want the line control to be visible in each page.

Kindly suggest how to resolve.

Here is the screenshot

[Report 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVV4F.png)

[Report 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJOGU.png)

Green area is the body section which should contains line (red line is line control), in the first page it is showing correctly but in the 2nd page it is invisible.

I want the red line should be visible in all the pages.

Comment: Please attach a picture that will show how you'd like your report will show

Comment: Here's the screenshot of what the problem is.

Comment: Now more understandable, but how exactly do you build the body area, attach a code and/or XAML.

Comment: I used a table control to build the body section and use line control between the column as marked as red in the screenshot. I also tried repeatwith tablix of the line property but nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, repeatwith property is even not working with rectange control also. Visual studio team must have to look over this issue.

Moreover, I had also noticed that the row header is also not visible on the next page as I tick the checkbox of repeat row header ... on the table property section. I think I had to put the row header in the header section to get repeated on the further pages.

Well after doing a lot of research I had concluded to use alternate method to acihieve this. I want to share this to have an alternate way. What I tried is :

1. Donot use line control
2. Putting border on the left and right side each column.
3. Fill the remaing table with the blank row to touch the footer section and fill the entire body section.

4.Suppose 1 page takes 17 rows to get fill and if the row is having greater than 17 suppose 20 then (17 - (20-17)) i.e 14 blank rows fill be filled

5. If table is having 5 rows then (17-5) i.e 12 blank rows will be filled.

I had achieved by trying this logic that can't be achieved through line control but I am not satisfying with this.